# Connection String in web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 at my local machine have no password and username. I am trying to connect data base I have given this connection string

```
<add name="NGO_MS" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;database=NGO_MS;integrated Security=SSPI;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm getting an error.

> Unrecognized configuration section add.

Kindly tell me the correct way to add a connection string.

Comment: Better to show all the section (lines before and after this)

Comment: Qualify for a bunch of downvotes

Comment: Look for the <add name=DefaultConnection and replace that key

Comment: Thanks I got the answer I was missing End tag of connection string. But I could not understand Why people give down votes :D

Comment: What did you do? Did you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I followed the below answerd suggesion and found that I was missing Connection strings end tag @Patrick Hofman

Comment: Read "downvote" concept, "This question does not show any research of effort...". You had a bug in your code not a problem and you preferred not to do any research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That element has to go inside the `<connectionStrings>` element, not directly in the `<configuration>` element.

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NGO_MS" connectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;database=NGO_MS;integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
```

Comment: Total lack of interest on reading a minimum documentation.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios: What do you mean?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I will cancel the downvote but I think we shouldn't spend time answering questions from people that didn't read for a second the documents, just to get more points in our accounts.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios Why would you bother downvoting the answer rather than the question?

Comment: Don't worry, I will give you the points back, for some people is more import to collect point for their accounts rather than improving the community. This kind of questions encourage developers to come to this site and get their jobs done by others. He didn't even tried to read the documents, configuration element is the most basic thing a developer learns in asp.net, he just wanted somebody else works for him instead of learning.

Comment: @Maximiliano Rios Yes you are right. Next time I will definately try by myself to solve the stuff.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios: Please read who's commenting. I'm not msm8bball.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios: Who are you answering to? Me or msm8bball? What are you going on about?